# How can i get the text of an item in context menu strip when clicked after populated programmatically?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the text of an ITEM in CONTEXT MENU STRIP when CLICKED after generated on runtime. I have already populated the ITEMS in CONTEXT MENU STRIP and added an event handler for click. The problem is I really don't know how to get the text of those items.

```
private void updateContext()
        {
            a_context_menu.Items.Clear();

            foreach (var a_device in a_devices)
            {
                var a_item = a_context_menu.Items.Add("A CONTEXT");
                var a_item = a_context_menu.Items.Add("B CONTEXT");

                a_item.Click += a_item_Click;
            }
        }

        private void a_item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a_item_Click.text);
        }
```

TYI

if a_context is clicked a message box will show with that item's text:

a_context

Comment: winform? or wpf?

Comment: i'm using winform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the "sender" to "ToolStripItem"

```
private void A_item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((ToolStripItem)sender).Text);
}
```

and... by the way, before you clear the items:

```
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
```

you need to remove the click event:

```
foreach (ToolStripItem ts in contextMenuStrip1.Items)
{
    ts.Click -= A_item_Click;
}

contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
```

Or there's a memory leak happens.

Answer (score 0):

just found the delegate function and i think it's the better approach.

```
    private void updateContextMenu()
    {    
         foreach (var a_device in a_devices)
         {
              var a_item = a_context_menu.Items.Add(aDevice.FullName);
              a_item.Click += delegate {
              a_item_Click(a_Device.FullName);
              };
    
         }
     }
    
    private void Mic_item_Click(string deviceName)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(a_deviceName);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).